# t-sql nearest quarter hour

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a way to return a value adjusted to the 'highest' quarter.  I cannot round because the value returned cannot be greater than the original value.  For example if the value is 53.290 I need to return 53.25 and 51.49 would return 51.25.  Can I do this in t-sql?

Comment: Can you multiply by four, truncate to integer and divide by four?

Comment: I didnt see your comment earlier.  If you add it as an answer I will flag it accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you've provided, Steve, of dividing by 0.25 has the same effect as this code. I'm not sure, but I feel that multiplication by four is clearer than divison by a fraction.

```
SELECT (FLOOR(@myValue * 4)) / 4.0
```

Comment: I agree, which is why you are getting the points for this one.

Answer (score 2):

After working on this for a bit and doing some more research I think this is the best solution.  Thanks everyone for the responses.

```
DECLARE @myvalue DECIMAL(8,4);
SET @myvalue = 53.26;

SELECT (Floor(@myvalue/.25)) * .25; -- Returns 53.25

SET @myvalue = 53.24;
SELECT (Floor(@myvalue/.25)) * .25; -- Returns 53.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Value DECIMAL(10,4) = 53.290;

SELECT ROUND(@Value/25.00, 2) * 25

Result: 53.250000000
```

Rounded value to TWO Digits

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ROUND(@Value/25.00, 2) * 25)

Result: 53.25
```

Comment: This rounds to .25 when the decimal value is greater than .125.  My original post was a bit unclear but I need it to return .00 when the decimal value is less than .25.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the nearest quarter based on the values present on the right side of the decimal.I have just tried my hands on it. Hope it would be useful. Just try it with different values as well.

```
DECLARE @Value DECIMAL(10, 2) = 53.49

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CAST(RIGHT(@Value, 2) AS FLOAT) > 0
            AND CAST(RIGHT(@Value, 2) AS FLOAT) <= 49
            THEN FLOOR(@Value) + 0.25
        WHEN CAST(RIGHT(@Value, 2) AS FLOAT) > 49
            AND CAST(RIGHT(@Value, 2) AS FLOAT) <= 74
            THEN FLOOR(@Value) + 0.50
        ELSE CEILING(@Value) - 0.25
        END
```